# kernel vulnerabilities

Tags: linux, kernel, security, vulnerability

I recently got [a single-board computer](http://com.odroid.com/sigong/blog/blog_list.php?bid=180) for which the official support has been discontinued.

I'm using a minimal, debootstrapped Debian on that system with a kernel that is taken from one of the official ubuntu images for that SBC. However, that image is already quite old and so is the kernel. Since I'm not interested in new features, my biggest concerns are kernel security vulnerabilities. Is there a way how to check which vulnerabilites are present in a given kernel, and which are critical for using that kernel for a certain purpose, e.g., as webserver?

**Edit**: Since the kernel is not managed by a package manager, `debsecan` shouldn't work, I guess.

Comment: Read the release notes of the versions that came later.